# Cannot access a disposed object in my long running process

Tags: asp.net, sockets, iis

Ive got a long running process in ASP.net which uses sockets to listen to data from some propriatary software. I have the following code to read data on port 13000. After a period of inactivity I get an exception stating that i cannot access a disposed object. I am aware that this is because the socket was closed because of a timeout or incorrect coding on my behalf. Its driving me crazy lol!! 
I basically want the socket to stay open until i close it, so I need the connection to be robust.

Could any of you guys spot some issues I am having. 
In a nutshell the code below establshes a TCP/IP connection and reads data. The data is processed as it comes in and is stored in an XML file.
The function "Update()" will compare the generated records in the XML to that of a CSV file and generate an output XML file. 
But basically it all works other than the connection keeps dropping out.
Thank you in advance for any help!!!

```
    {

        System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener server = null;
        try
        {
            // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
            Int32 port = 13000;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Any;
            server = new System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener(localAddr, port);           
            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();
            const int recsize = 39;
            const int outputsize = 39;
            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[4096];
            String data = null;

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
               System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");
                data = null;
                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;
                int x = 0;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    // data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetString(bytes,0,i);
                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    data = data.ToUpper();
                    var Data_out1 = ("AnnouncerKit@AckPong@$");
                    var Data_out2 = ("AnnouncerKit@Ping@$");
                    var Data_out4 = ("AnnouncerKit@GetInfo@$");
                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                    var Data_In = data.ToString().Split('@');
                    byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data_out1);
                    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data_out1);
                    byte[] buffer2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data_out2);
                    byte[] buffer4 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data_out4);
                    var Data_out3 = ("AnnouncerKit@AckStore@" + Data_In[Data_In.Length - 2] + "@$");
                    byte[] buffer3 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Data_out3);
                    if (Data_In[1] == "PONG")
                    {
                        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        stream.Write(buffer2, 0, buffer2.Length);
                    }
                    if (Data_In[1] == "ACKPING")
                    {
                        stream.Write(buffer4, 0, buffer4.Length);

                    }
                    if (Data_In[1] == "STORE")
                    {
                        stream.Write(buffer3, 0, buffer3.Length);
                        Response.Write(Data_In[0]);

                    }          
                    var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
                    //  TextBox1.Text = date.ToString();

                    var save = Request.QueryString["Racename"].ToString() + "_" + date + ".xml";
                    // var save = "RaceData_" + date + ".xml";
                    //   String SaveDirectory = Server.MapPath.SaveDirectory((save));
                    string directoryMyLaps = Server.MapPath("~/MYLAPS Files/");
                    Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(directoryMyLaps);
                    if (!File.Exists(save))
                    {
                        System.Xml.Linq.XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("bodies"));

                        doc.Save(save); //save with todays date and event name
                    }
                    System.Xml.XmlDocument doc2 = new XmlDocument();

                    doc2.Load(save);
                    foreach (string s in data.Split('@'))
                    {
                        if (s.Length == recsize)
                        {
                            //   Console.WriteLine(data);
                            //  TextBox1.Text = data;
                            string racerdata = s.Substring(0, outputsize);
                            // XmlElement test = doc2.CreateElement("RaceData");
                            XmlElement fileElement = doc2.CreateElement("body");
                            XmlElement boxName = doc2.CreateElement("Device_Name");
                            XmlElement bibid = doc2.CreateElement("ChipCode");
                            XmlElement time = doc2.CreateElement("Time");
                            bibid.InnerText = racerdata.Substring(0, 7);
                            fileElement.AppendChild(bibid);
                            boxName.InnerText = Data_In[0];
                            fileElement.AppendChild(boxName);
                            time.InnerText = racerdata.Substring(7, 13);
                            fileElement.AppendChild(time);
                            //Here getting the root element 
                            //Here appending the "File" element to the root element. 
                            XmlElement rootElement = (XmlElement)doc2.SelectSingleNode("bodies");
                            rootElement.AppendChild(fileElement);                                                  
                        }
                    }                
                        doc2.Save(save);
                        Update(); //function that compares the received XML data to a CSV
                    }

                }                
                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
             //   Update();
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
           // server.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", ex);
        }
        finally
        {

            // Stop listening for new clients.
            server.Stop();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure whatever you are trying to connect to is not closing the connection forcefully?

Comment: Hi James_Parsons, I am fairly certain that it doesn't as its documentation states that i maintains a connection.

Comment: Sometimes it will go minutes without receiving any data, it seems fine when it gets data. it stays connected